# Is there a way to catch maximum length PER LINE and not allow user to input more characters if max length PER LINE has been reached?

Tags: c#

Good day!

Sorry if I cant make it into code but here's my problem:

Im coding C#, using TextBox Control, Multiline = true.

Now, my problem is i need to know the user's input (per line) whether it already reaches maximum length PER LINE defined. If yes, it shouldn't be printed in the textbox (like MaxLength does).

Example of the input (Note: maximum length per line is 5):

```
Dog //3 characters
Cat //3 characters
Telephone //9 characters
```

Telephone shouldn't be printed coz it exceeded max length per line which is 5. It should be "Telep" only.



**EDITED:**

Acctually, I found my way to solve this. it was as simple as this!!!!

```
if (txtText.Lines[txtText.GetLineFromCharIndex(txtText.SelectionStart)].Length > Convert.ToInt32(txtMaxlen.Text) - 1 && e.KeyChar!=8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Just put that code in "OnKeyPress" event then VIOLA!

Comment: Nope it should be `dogca` since you said its 5 length per line.

Comment: acctually, dog, cat and telephone have different lines like Dog is on the 1st line, Cat is on the 2nd line then Telephone is on the 3rd line. so dog and cat should be printed because they are below 5 characters yet Telephone is greater than 5 so when user tries to input the word telephone (or any string exceeds 5), program will only be able to display "Telep"

Comment: You should have mentioned that :) as since you did not I was under the idea you have all the 3 on the same line with a 5 length limit. Either way is word wrap not of your interest I mean is there a reason u want to limit it to a given length as in to keep the user within the textbox sight or something like that ? Also do u want that to happen as the user writes or after he finish or after he press a button ?

Comment: I did input it on different lines but i didn't know why it displayed like that. Anyway, I'm revising my program where textbox shouldn't display text input if it reaches the limit (which is in the example, is 5). (Just like "TextBox.Maxlength" does)

Comment: fixed that for you about the lines. Well I guess your best bet then would be to have a OnTextChange event that will check everything and remove characters where they should not be, something similar to what was replied by Chibueze. This way as soon as new text comes in if it goes above the length it gets removed right away but might as well put some weight to your app.

Comment: Thank you! haha. I'm new here in stackoverflow so i dont know how to post yet. I found a solution (more of a work-around) and i think its working fine. how can i post it? so that people w/ the same prob would find an answer (atleast) to their question hehehe :P

Comment: @JackForst there should be a button at the end called `Answer Your Question` which you can use to post a solution you found to your problem if no other reply is suitable for it. Besides that you can when needed edit your own Question by clicking on the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17079046/edit) text near the end of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle [OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) event and then use [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property to get array of lines. Then simply check whenever any line has more characters than you allow and if so - correct it and set as a `Lines` again. You have to also prevent event from rising when you do such *correction*, use the flag or unsubscribe/subscribe technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract them from the lines of the Textbox like:

```
var myarr = myTextBox.Lines.Select(n => n.Remove(3)).ToArray();
```

Btw, you're most likely better off with a DataGridView Control.

Comment: What the above code does is simply that when the user has entered all input and you want to retrieve their input, the above code would do that and return only the first three characters for each line in a string array. You can easily put it back in the textbox by replacing `myarr` with `myTextBox.Lines`

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox.OnTextChanged += (EventArgs e) => // invoked on every text change
{
    var lines = myTextBox.Where(x.Length > 5); // Get the long lines
    for (var i; i < lines.Count(); i++)  // iterate over long lines
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].Substring(0, 5); // replace the line with its substring(stripped) value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, this should behave like the `MaxLength` property and handle the addition of the new char before it occurs, not after. When a key is pressed it checks the length of the line the cursor is currently on.

```
public class MaxPerLineTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MaxPerLineTextBox()
    {
        base.Multiline = true;
    }

    public override bool Multiline
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }

        set
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Readonly subclass");
        }
    }

    public int? MaxPerLine { get; set; }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            return;
        }

        int maxPerLine;
        if (this.MaxPerLine.HasValue)
        {
            maxPerLine = this.MaxPerLine.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            return;           
        }

        var count = 0;
        var lineLength = this.Lines.Select(line =>
            {
                count += line.Length;
                return new { line.Length, count };
            })
            .Last(c => c.count < this.SelectionStart).Length;

        if (lineLength < maxPerLine)
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            return;
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not quite sure how to use your class. Sorry, Im a bit a beginner to C#