# Text length exceeding maximum allowed text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using textbox and here's my problem...

I already have a handler where program will not allow anymore inputs when defined Maximum text length is reached. Here's the code:

```
private void txtText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtText.Text.Length > MaxLengthAllowed - 1 && e.KeyChar != 8)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Console.Beep(2000, 90);
        return;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when I press and HOLD a key (for example the letter A), it exceeds the "MaxLengthAllowed" then beeps.

Is this a fault or something like a limitation of the textbox? Or am I missing something?

This code is working fine when you are not HOLDING a key. Hence, that's my problem.

Comment: You make it beep right `Console.Beep(2000, 90);`?

Comment: you are telling it to beep *AFTER* it exceeds.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel - Yes, I'm making it beep once it reaches the maximim text

Comment: @James - Nope, it will beep once the maximum allowed has been reached.

Comment: If you want to beep once go for `TextChanged` event

Comment: the beeping is not my problem. my problem is text is EXCEEDING my defined MAXLENGTHALLOWED

Comment: It depends. Like for example, MaxLengthAllowed = 15; now if i HOLD a key like in my post, text length exceeds to 17 and sometimes 19

Comment: @EhsanUllah you're wrong check it out

Comment: @JackFrost What kind of `TextBox` are you using? If the `Beep` is still generated when the text length exceeds the max length, `e.Handled = true;` should also be executed, that's strange. You should make a totally new demo and try it yourself. Your current project has something wrong here.

Comment: I just tried out my code in a clean solution and it was working fine. I guess there's something wrong with my project. I'll just check it out at the moment and will keep you guys posted. Thank you for the support and sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 1):

Just set the MaxLength property of the textbox. It's as simple as

```
textboxVar.MaxLength = maxLengthAllowed;
```

Hope that helps.

You could always subscribe a PropertyChanged event, which you can rig to fire whenever the Text property of the textbox changes. Have a read of how to [raise an event on Property Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed)

Comment: Thank you for this but I'm acctually using a multiline textbox and I cant do that. I just made my question like that to make it simpler. here's my original post way back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079046/is-there-a-way-to-catch-maximum-length-per-line-and-not-allow-user-to-input-more

Comment: @JackFrost after reading your original post i can say that your this question conveys entirely different meaning

Comment: You could say that. That's why I made a new post. Coz here, my problem is Text length is exceeding MaxLengthAllowed when a user HOLDS a key...

Comment: @JackFrost if you set the above property it won't

Answer (score 0):

You could use the KeyUp event instead. That only fires once when you release the key. KeyPress will be fired multiple times for as long as you hold down the key.

Comment: You say "That only fires once when you release the key", but my code can ALMOST handle it? for example, MaxLengthAllowed = 15; now if i HOLD a key like in my post, text length exceeds to 17 and sometimes 19 ONLY and not to infinity.

Comment: As far as i can see, your code will run indefinitely until you release the key. It will continue to beep as long as you text length will be equal or greater then the max length allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox.Text` is not updated when `TextBox.KeyPress` is fired. For example, if the `Text` before `KeyPress` is `A`, When user types `B`, the `Text` is still `A` (not `AB`) in the `KeyPress` event handler. So you have to define your `MaxLengthAllowed` to be 1 less than the desired value. The code should look like this:

```
private void txtText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if ((txtText.Text.Length > MaxLengthAllowed - 1) && e.KeyChar != 8)
  {
    e.Handled = true;
    Console.Beep(2000, 90);      
  }
}
```

I think you should use `TextBox.MaxLength` property instead, it also supports `Beep`, the `Beep sound` is even nicer than the `Beep` generated by `Console.Beep()`.

Comment: Thank you for this but as I have reviewed my code, I already have "MaxLengthAllowed - 1"

Comment: @JackFrost if so, I can't reproduce your problem, it CAN'T exceed the desired max length that way.

Comment: That's what I thought as well... Try doing my code in your end then you'll see. hahaha. kinda frustrating though..:(

Comment: @JackFrost I have tried your code as well (not by logic only).