# textbox multiline, length issues

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have a `textbox` with `multiline` set to true. I want to have `max characters` set to **50 per line** with a **total of 3 lines**. When they reach the 50 characters, I would like it to jump to the second line. 
I am having some issues and have been struggling with this for a while and wanted to know if anyone can help.

```
MAX_LINE_COUNT = 3

Private Sub txtMsg_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtMsg.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = (Me.txtMsg.Lines.Length >= MAX_LINE_COUNT)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Lines` is an array, so your code will not work because you are checking the amount of lines in the text box, not the amount of characters in a single line.

Comment: You have to come up with your own code. Check whether the length meets your requirements and create a new line (for example: SendKeys.Send("{Enter}") to simulate enter). Also bear in mind that you have to check the textBox.Width property. This is the "crappy" approach. In general, when doing more or less fancy things with input text, you should rely on the RichTextBox control (allows you to do many more things that a TextBox). A still better approach would be creating your own textBox with its own properties. In any case, there is not too much to explain, just writing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To effectively handle multiple lines of text with a common max characters per line, then you will need to extend the `TextBox` class and override several items in the `TextBox` class. Instead of re-inventing the wheel, I am going to redirect you to the code from an answer to [Is there a way to catch maximum length PER LINE and not allow user to input more characters if max length PER LINE has been reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079046/is-there-a-way-to-catch-maximum-length-per-line-and-not-allow-user-to-input-more), since it is not the accepted answer, I will paste the VB.NET translation below:

```
Public Class MaxPerLineTextBox
  Inherits TextBox
  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.Multiline = True
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Property Multiline() As Boolean
    Get
      Return True
    End Get
    Set
      Throw New InvalidOperationException("Readonly subclass")
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property MaxPerLine() As System.Nullable(Of Integer)
    Get
      Return m_MaxPerLine
    End Get
    Set
      m_MaxPerLine = Value
    End Set

  End Property

  Private m_MaxPerLine As System.Nullable(Of Integer)

  Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyPress(e As KeyPressEventArgs)
    If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
      MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
      Return
    End If

    Dim maxPerLine As Integer
    If Me.MaxPerLine.HasValue Then
      maxPerLine = Me.MaxPerLine.Value
    Else
      MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
      Return
    End If

    Dim activeLine As Integer = Me.GetLineFromCharIndex(Me.SelectionStart)
    Dim lineLength As Integer = Me.SelectionStart - Me.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(activeLine)

    If lineLength < maxPerLine Then
      MyBase.OnKeyPress(e)
      Return
    End If

    e.Handled = True
  End Sub
End Class
```

To use the above code you will need to do the following:

1. Create a new project in your solution to hold the code above.
2. Paste code above into new project and build it.
3. Ensure that there are no errors and the project compiles successfully.
4. The MaxPerLineTextBox control should show up in the toolbox. If it does not, then try restarting Visual Studio.
5. Drag MaxPerLineTextBox onto your form and set the properties.

Comment: VB.NET has changed a lot since I used it one hour ago :)

Comment: @Karl Anderson -- can you help me put this into VB.Net?

Comment: There are a couple of errors in this conversion but you have worked more than enough for a so brief question: +1 for you.

Comment: @varocarbas - Please feel free to edit my conversion errors. :-)

Comment: No thanks, I am good. But note that are pretty clear ones: this code cannot compile. I guess that the OP is the one who should work on this, he has already got quite a lot "for free".

Comment: @user1884032 - I suggest that you post the C# version of LINQ and ask for help to convert it.

Comment: @user1884032 I changed the posted code.  I fixed the compile error by changing `Return New From` to `Return New With` but the function didn't work when the cursor was on the first line, so I replaced the lineLength algorithm.  Karl, feel free to roll back if the change isn't warranted.

Comment: @LarsTech - thanks, I am not a VB.NET developer and the syntax that I got when I used a converter, even Reflector, would not compile. Appreciated.