# How should I handle filling multiple textboxes when I don't know how many of them will have data?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, list, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing an application in VB in which I need to show the user some information which will be copy and pasted into another application however limitations of the other application mean that the string needs to be split into chunks no larger than 55 characters (it's just written notes).  I thought the neatest way to do this was to have several textboxes each with a 'copy to clipboard' button to make it convenient for the user.

The code I have is:

```
Dim invdesc As List(Of String) = Split(splitstring, 55)
                    txtinvDesc1.Text = invdesc(0)
                    txtinvDesc2.Text = invdesc(1)
                    txtinvDesc3.Text = invdesc(2)
                    ...
```

Split uses a regular expression to return a list of several lines without breaking up words and **most** of the time this will return a maximum of seven results but occasionally six (my original string max length is 330) and often fewer so my original idea to fill out any strings shorter than 330 with trailing spaces won't work as it's still possible I will either miss text or call a result that isn't there.

Ideally I would just do some kind of loop that only inputs to txtinvDesc(x) while there is data available and ignores the rest (or hides them) but I don't know any way to refer to a textbox other than explicitly or how to put them in any kind of list/array.

So it's a bit of an open question in "how best can I handle this requirement?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to index the tbs:

```
Private TBs as New List (of TextBox)
```

Early on (after FormLoad) maybe in a FormSetup:

```
TBs.Add(txtinvDesc1)
TBs.Add(txtinvDesc2)
TBs.Add(txtinvDesc3)
...
```

Then:

```
Dim invdesc As List(Of String) = Split(splitstring, 55)

For n As Integer = 0 To invdesc.Count-1
     TBs(n).Text = invdesc(n)
Next

' handle the varying 7th TB:
For n As Integer = invdesc.Count-1 To TBs.Count - 1
     TBs(n).Enabled = False
     TBs(n).Text =""
Next
```

Or a For/Each:

```
Dim ndx As Integer = 0
For Each tb As TextBox In TBs
    tb.Text = invdesc(ndx)
    ndx += 1                     ' thanks varo!
Next
```

Then hide/disable or at least clear the text from any empty ones.

If it turns out there are always 6 you really only need an if statement:

```
txtinvDesc1.Text = invdesc(0)
txtinvDesc2.Text = invdesc(1)
txtinvDesc3.Text = invdesc(2)
...
If incDesc.Count-1 = 6 Then              
     txtinvDesc7.Text = invdesc(6)
Else
     txtinvDesc7.Enabled= False
     txtinvDesc7.Text = ""
End If
```

I would change the TB names to start at `txtinvDesc0.Text` to avoid getting confused (as I may have)

Comment: There is no problem with my code. Why you have said something which does not have any point?

Comment: It is pretty ironical that you have (wrongly) critised something which actually is present in your code: you use tb.Text = invdesc(ndx) but don't increase the index!!! ndx is always zero!!!

Comment: you are right, there is no problem for a generic solution.  That solution would have to be altered for the OPs SPECIFIC situation of 7 Destinations and only 6 Data Sources, thats all! `ctr.Text = invdesc(mappingList.IndexOf(ctr.Name))` WILL crash when there are only 6 in the array.  Dont be so defensive.

Comment: @varocarbas  I think your method is fine and never said otherwise (esp never that it was "WRONG") - it just would not fit the OPs situation.  Original comment was to the OP telling what he would have to fix.

Comment: You are welcome. This is how things should be done: if I know that you have a problem, I help you to fix it (same thing expect from you). But if you don't understand something, you should ask, instead of saying that something is wrong. My approaches fits PERFECTLY into the OP's requirements and into any other requirement

Comment: I insist: what I proposed is a basic mapping approach, the pre-requisite is mapping ALL THE TARGET ITEMS. If the OP has 7 target items, he would have to add 7 items to the map (if 8, 8; if 10, 10; etc.). If the number of target items differ from the target properties (name of textboxes), he would have to let various values blank. But the size of both arrays (original list and mapping list) HAVE TO BE IDENTICAL NO MATTER WHAT.

Comment: In summary: no problem with you at all (didn't like the award/un-award attitude of the OP, just this), but next time. Unless having a clear bug, try to not conclude that something is wrong if you don't understand it. Try to ask firstly ("have you accounted for this fact?"), it would also help to the answerer to transmit ideas clearer (I thought that the mapping ideas was evident but I was wrong); and would avoid people with not too much knowledge coming to wrong conclusions (now, the OP, or any future reader).

Comment: Dude, the issue is NOT THE TARGET - it is the data source!  For a generic method, one he would have to modify, it is FINE.  It does not address the specific sitation of MORE targets than DATA elements which is all I was pointing out.  `Split(splitstring, 55)` is not going to create a 7th item everytime! ....and I am NOT unclear on anything...

Comment: If you do any mapping approach (like here: the index of this has to be related with the index of that), ALL THE ELEMENTS HAVE TO ACCOUNTED FOR. I learned my lesson. Next time, instead of writing 3 elements, I will write the 7 elements and show how you can let one blank. But, stop thinking that you are right, because you are not: I might not have transmitted the ideas as clearly as you need, but this is it. Don't disccuss about what is un-discussable: you cannot set a mapping system where all the elements are not accounted for.

Comment: PLEASE AWARD THIS GUY THE ANSWER BEFORE HE HAS AN ANEURYSM.

Comment: Take it easy, duuude. I don't want the award; points do not matter to me (I have quite a few already :)). What matters is something being right or not. And what annoys me (a bit) are this kind of behaviour of awarding or up-voting or down-voting arbitrarily. All this has a point (showing what is right; promoting what is right; and correcting what is wrong); if you prefer to follow your own rules; at least, accept when people (= I) corrects you. Your correction of my answer was wrong. This is it. And take it easy because life is too long.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a collection (e.g., `Array` or `List`) of `TextBox` like with any other type/class (as you are doing with `String` in your code). Sample:

```
Dim allTextBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)
allTextBoxes.Add(txtinvDesc1)
allTextBoxes.Add(txtinvDesc2)
allTextBoxes.Add(txtinvDesc3)
```

Alternatively, you might iterate through all the controls in the main form by checking its type (a textbox or not). In that case you would have to set a relationship between the given name of the textbox and the data list index, via other collection for example:

```
Dim mappingList As New List(Of String)
mappingList.Add("txtinvDesc1")
mappingList.Add("txtinvDesc2")
mappingList.Add("txtinvDesc3")

For Each ctr As Control In Me.Controls
    If (TypeOf ctr Is TextBox AndAlso mappingList.Contains(ctr.Name)) Then
        ctr.Text = invdesc(mappingList.IndexOf(ctr.Name))
    End If
Next
```

--- CLARIFICATION (not as evident as I thought)

The proposed for  each loop relies on a mapping approach, that is, it relates each element in `invdesc` with the corresponding TextBox name. By definition, both arrays HAVE TO have the same number of elements (otherwise the mapping system wouldn't have made any sense). This is the most efficient and overall-applicable alternative; if the names of the textboxes and `invdesc` have elements in common (e.g., the numbers), you might just compare the names. BUT WHEN MAPPING YOU HAVE TO ACCOUNT FOR ALL THE ELEMENTS (if there is no associated TextBox to a given item, let the value blank; but all the items have to be accounted).

Comment: Thank you, so easy when you know how!

Comment: the for loop will need to be modified to test the size of the array - the OP states 'usually 7 but sometimes 6'.

Comment: @Plutonix The proposed approach cannot work without mappingList and for that you have to know the number of textBoxes (their names). This loop can deal as it is with any size but the corresponding Lists (indvdesc and mappingList) will have to be populated with all the elements. On the hand, I didn't propose a specific solution for the specific problems of the OP but two more-or-less-generic approaches to deal with the given problem, that is: iterating through an undefined number of TextBoxes; the OP is expected to adapt this code to his specific requirements (or ask for further help).

Comment: @Plutonix but, in any case, your statement "modified to test the size of the array" is wrong (not sure why it got a +1). This approaches comes from a pre-requisite: both lists have to have identical number of elements, otherwise the mapping would work. This is implicit in the proposal. Also, note that the proposed mapping was just an alternative (because I don't know the expected names); it might even not be required to set mappingList and just look for occurrences in the names.

Comment: @LostRob Why have you un-awarded this as the right solution? You are free to choose any alternative, but I consider doing this when there is nothing wrong with my code (other than the Plutonix misunderstanding, completely unmotivated) pretty bad.

Comment: @LostRob If you haven't read what I wrote to Plutonix, I will explain it to you too (next time ask, such that you can make a decision with a minimum knowledge): I don't know the names and thus I proposed a mapping approach. LOGICALLY, you have to add the same number of elements in mappingList and in invdesc and, thus, by definition there might no problem with the size. The basic idea in a mapping system is that ALL THE ELEMENTS have to get its mapped equivalent. Next time, please, ask (ideally, someone knowing what he is talking about).

Comment: @varocarbas He knows the array will have 6 or 7 items, he knows he has 7 TBs on the form.  He just wanted a way to ref them in a loop AND handle the perhaps unusual case of 6 items in the array.  he is not dynamically creating TBs (and he does not have to loop thru every control on the form to find them). both lists are NOT identical which was a key part of his Q.

Comment: @Plutonix please, read my last update and get the ideas properly before saying so wrong things: BOTH LIST HAVE TO BE OF IDENTICAL SIZE, this is the whole point of a mapping system, you have to map each single element. If there are more element of one type than of other, you might let the contents blank, but the mapping array has to contain all the items to be mapped.

Comment: @LostRob you know... from you nick I thought that I knew you. From your attitude, I am still more sure. In any case (even if I am wrong and I don't know you at all), I know you already: nice to meet you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use multiline textbox and in OnKeyPress event force 55 chars per line. You can find subclassed TextBox with that feature in this SO answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17082189/351383